# Database Modification Scripts - Rollout / Rollback Best Practice?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm looking for insight into best practices regarding database scripting for modifications that go out along side other code changes for a software system.

I used to work for a company that insisted that every roll out has a roll back ready in case of issues. This sounds sensible, but in my opinion, the roll back code for database modifications deployed via scripts has the same likely hood of failing as the roll out script.

For managed code, version control makes this quite simple, but for a database schema, rolling back changes is not so easy - especially if data is changed as part of the roll out.

My current practice is to test the roll out code by running against a test database during late stage development, and then run the application against that test database. Following this, I back up the live DB, and proceed with the roll out.

I'm yet to run into a problem, but am wondering how other shops manage database changes, and what the strategy is for recovering from any bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of our database scripts go through several test phases against databases that are like our live database.  This way we can be fairly certain that the modification scripts will work as expected.

For rolling back, stored procedures, views, functions, triggers, everything programmatic is easy to roll back, just apply the previous version of the object.

Like you mentioned, the challenging part comes when updating / deleting records from tables, or even adding new columns to tables.  And you're right that in this case the rollback can be just as likely to fail.

What we do is if we have a change that can't be easily rolled back, but is a sensitive / critical section... is that we have a set rollback scripts that also go through the same testing environments.  We run the update script, validate that it works as expected, and then run the rollback script, and validate that it works as it did prior to the modification.

Another thing that we do as just a precaution is to create a database snapshot (SQL Server 2005) prior to an update.  That way if there are any unexpected issues, we can use the snapshot to recover any data that was potentially lost during the update.

So the safest course of action is to test against databases that are as close to your live system as possible, and to test your rollback scripts as well... and just in case both of those fail, have a snapshot ready just in case you need it.

Comment: Thanks, that confirmed much of my experience. Sounds like my web shop (and project) is a bit smaller than yours, so testing to the extent that you do is a bit beyond my budgetary constraints, but some good mechanisms there.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Diff (or something like it is always helpful if you are using a test database. It has a lot of checks and balances, safeguards, and ways of restoring or rolling back if there is an issue. Very useful.

http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diff.aspx